# Compiling compatibility issue external libraries

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, compiler-errors, compatibility

I were trying to use the Selenium WebDriver for an Android application. (I am using the latest AndroidStudio; v2.2)

I followed [this guide](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/04/setting-up-selenium-webdriver-in.html) so in the lib's my app I copied the jar files (the downloaded zip of Selenium WebDriver has a folder named "libs", a jar named "client-combined-3.0.0-beta4-nodeps" and a DEPENDENCIES and a LICENSE file[I've just copied all the jars in the "libs" folder and the other jar outside])

[image: Here's a screenshot with all the libs.]

Here's the build.gradle (**module:app**)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.utente.downall"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        pickFirst("META-INF/LICENSE")
        pickFirst("META-INF/DEPENDENCIES")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/client-combined-3.0.0-beta4-nodeps.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/guava-19.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar')
    compile files('libs/phantomjsdriver-1.3.0.jar')
}
```

(Project synched)

While executing "run" I had this error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

So I've gone to the build.gradle (**Project: DownAll**) and I added these target/source compatibility, so here's what's like:

[image: Screnshot]

I cleaned the project, rebuilded it, re-synched it but still the same error.
What should I do?

If it can help, here's my environment variables, if it can help:

JAVA_HOME

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102

ANDROID_HOME

C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

(AppData folder is hidden)

EDIT:

UP

Comment: Did you try adding the two statements it suggested? 
`targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'`

Comment: @BR89 as you can see in the second screenshot, yes, I did (I've done it in the build.gradle project)

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that.  -- Using JDK 1.8..I'm curious what would happen if you tried utilizing 1.7 or lower

Comment: @BR89 well, I tried and it gives the same error: maybe I'm doing it wrong, but the library submodule doesn't get compiled with Java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the exact same error and figured out that `com.google.guava:guava:21.0` was causing the problem; app starts working right after downgrading it to 20.0.

So, I guess some of your jars might be incompatible.

Try downgrading / removing dependencies one by one.